# SharePoint 2013 SafeControls - from wsp manifest to web.config refuses to use System.Web.Entity assembly name

Tags: 2013, web-config, safe-controls

I have added the following safe control to a feature in my SharePoint 2013 solution:

```
<SafeControl Name="System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSource" Assembly="System.Web.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" TypeName="EntityDataSource" IsSafe="true" IsSafeAgainstScript="false" />
```

This gets added to the feature file `SharePointProjectItem.spdata`.

When the solution is being deployed (currently) it will add the following to the web.config:

```
<SafeControl Assembly="AcmeCorp.Foo, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3333332222211111" Namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" TypeName="EntityDataSource" />
```

But it replaces the assembly name with my own custom assembly name!

### Question

Can you not add external, ala Microsoft assembly controls as safe controls to a web.config?

It feels like a bug to me.